# Первая встреча сообщества Stack Overflow на русском в Минске 2–го августа 2018

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, встречи-сообщества

Stack Overflow — не социальная сеть, у нас нет списков друзей и личных сообщений. В то же время, все, что делается на сайте, делается исключительно сообществом и для сообщества.

**С нетерпением спешу анонсировать первую встречу участников сообщества Stack Overflow на русском в прекрасном городе Минске!**

Главная цель встречи — свободное общение с коллегами разработчиками, которого иногда не хватает на сайте. Также вы сможете задать любые интересующие вас вопросы относительно сайта, посмотреть на статистику сообщества и многое другое.

Мы планируем встретиться через две недели, в четверг 2–го августа. Место встречи выбираете вы! После определения места и времени я отпишусь всем участникам на почту из учётной записи, указанную в анкете Google Forms.

Чтобы организовать встречу, нам необходима ваша помощь! Если вы планируете посетить мероприятие, пожалуйста, заполните [специальную форму](https://goo.gl/i8hQfW).

С нетерпением ждем встречи с вами!

Comment: Второго августа - день, конечно хороший. Но вот если бы она была назначена на дату поближе к Полумарафону... )))

Comment: Никто кроме нас?

Comment: Середина недели; не самый распространенный среди участников сообщества город — далеко не у всех, кто бы хотел, получится приехать.

Comment: @PeterSamokhin Четверг — самый распространенный день для мероприятий любого характера. 4 города, с которых на SOru наибольшее количество участников: Москва, Киев, Санкт–Петербург, Минск. Очень бы хотелось и в остальных трех городах тоже устроить встречи в ближайшем будущем. Приходите!

Comment: @AnT Полумарафон совсем не скоро. Можно устроить свой. Если у вас получится, напишите, пожалуйста, захвачу кроссовки. :)

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, "Так же вы можете задать .. вопросы ..... и многое другое". Вот, например, у меня задача по .net. Можно ли подъехать только лишь с целью спросить вопросы по этой задаче и надеждой получить ответы? (пока очень предварительно); ну, конечно, послушать о чем говорят за одно.

Comment: @AndreyK. Приходите! С большой вероятностью, у нас будет несколько .NET–специалистов. И, пожалуйста, не забудьте задать вопрос на сайте заранее. :)

Comment: @vp_arth, традиционные купания айтишников в фонтанах?

Comment: @АндрейNOP программист воздушно-десантных войск?

Comment: @AndreyK. K я точно буду на встрече, можете мне вопрос по .net задать :)

Comment: @АндрейNOP у нас тут последние 3 дня на улице и так купание, без фонтанов :(

Comment: @PashaPash аватарка почти под дату.

Comment: [Обсуждение встречи в чат-комнате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80973/minsk-02-08-2018)