# С Новым 7E3 Годом!

Tags: поддержка, итоги-года

Оглядываясь на уходящий год, сложно назвать его самым легким для нашего сообщества. На мой взгляд, этот год запомнился личностями куда более, чем событиями. В связи с этим, хочу выделить нескольких участников:

- В первую очередь хочется выразить огромную благодарность модераторам сообщества [@Nick Volynkin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/181472/nick-volynkin), [@Nofate](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/1984/nofate), [@PashaPash](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/177221/pashapash), [@Qwertiy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178988/qwertiy),
  [@ЮрийСПб](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/17609/). Тревоги обрабатываются очень быстро. Отдельно стоит отметить @ЮрийСПб, который работает как минимум за двоих в этом направлении.
- Не могу не сказать еще одно огромное спасибо [@PashaPash](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/177221/pashapash), который в этом году проделал колосальный труд по поддержке сообщества как на Мете, так и в чате.
- Большая благодарность нашему шеф-переводчику [@älёxölüt](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176217/) за огромный вклад в улучшение переводов интерфейса сайта.
- Спасибо [@Grundy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/186999/grundy), у которого (доказано эмпирически) лучше всех получается модерация общей чат–комнаты.
- Спасибо всем, кто смог найти время и посетил [встречи-сообщества](/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0), которые в том году состоялись в [Санкт-Петербурге](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6757/6) [Минске](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7535/6) и [Праге](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8257/6). Было крайне приятно с познакомиться с вами вне сайта.

*Большое спасибо всем, кто делится знаниями с сообществом! Без вас жизнь многих русскоязычных разработчиков была бы куда сложнее!*

Это лишь малая часть тех участников, о ком стоило бы написать… Хм. Почему бы не сделать это вместе? Давайте напишем обо всех вместе! Знаете участника, который много помогал вам или другим и хотели бы его поблагодарить за доброту и отзывчивость? Пожалуйста, напишите ответ к этому вопросу рассказав всем об участнике, и чего замечательного этот участник сделал! Завершим уходящий года благодарностью друг другу!

#### Год в цифрах

```
 -------------------------------------------------------------
|                    | Stack Overflow     |  Stack Overflow   |
|                    | на русском         |  на русском       |
|                    | 2017 год           |  2018 год         |
|--------------------|--------------------|-------------------|
|  Задано вопросов   |     65 363         |    86 573         |
|--------------------|--------------------|-------------------|
|Опубликовано ответов|     62 819         |    70 969         |
|--------------------|--------------------|-------------------|
|  Новых участников  |     44 182         |    39 557         |
 -------------------------------------------------------------
```

Сообщество растет каждый день, как и создаваемая нами база знаний. В уходящем году сообщество проделало невероятную работу, это видно по цифрам. Огромное спасибо всем, кто активно участвует в жизни русскоязычного сообщества разработчиков!

#### Несколько мыслей о будущем

Я бы хотел выделить наиболее важные аспекты развития, которые могут сыграть ключевую роль:

- *Больше людей — больше идей!* Было бы очень здорово в новом году увидеть всех, кто был частью Stack Overflow в течение прошлых лет, и много новых коллег, которые обязательно привнесут в сообщество «частичку себя»: кто–то поделится знаниями про интерфейс пользователя, кто–то с энтузиазмом расскажет про драйверы, а кто–то добавит в сообщество новые процессы! Реальные люди — самая важная часть Stack Overflow. Пригласите коллег в сообщество делиться знаниями, расскажите им о нашей [миссии](/help/manifesto). Уверен, они сделают участие в сообществе ещё интереснее.
- *Лучшие практики и общие проблемы международных сообществ на MSE.* Мы можем значительно повысить нашу эффективность обмениваясь идеями друг с другом на MSE. Кроме того, наши общие проблемы получат дополнительное внимание и новые интересные решения. С большой вероятностью, совместная работа ускорит темпы развития каждого международного сообщества. Как говорится, одна голова — хорошо, а много из разных культур — еще лучше!
- *База знаний своими руками*. Если отсортировать все вопросы по количеству просмотров, то можно увидеть, что на каждом международном сайте в топ-3 вошел хотя бы один вопрос с ответом от автора вопроса (к слову, это верно и для Stack Overflow на английском). Часто такие вопросы — это знания о технологии или подходе представленные в каноническом виде. Как показывает практика, они невероятно востребованы среди наших коллег. Было бы очень здорово в следующем году увидеть больше интересных вопросов суммирующих лучшие практики от участников сообщества. Уверен, подобные вопросы привлекут много внимания и положительных отзывов.

Я верю, что возможность повлиять на жизни тысяч людей всего одним ответом была, есть и будет главным мотиватором и вознаграждением от участия на сайте. Было бы здорово, если бы в новом году мы вместе сосредоточились на главном — свободной базе знаний и нашем сообществе. Уверен, дружная работа над созданием знаний принесет нам много положительных эмоций.

**Большое спасибо всем участникам сообщества [Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/)! Поздравляю с наступающим Новым Годом и желаю всего наилучшего! Буду рад видеть вас в новом году! Нас всех ждет много интересного!**

[image]

- Почти забыл! [Новый Год никогда не приходит один...](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8460/6)
- Новогодний конкурс по созданию анимации на новогодние темы завершился, но ребята его решили продлить  на 7 дней. Так как многие писали, что хотели поучаствовать, но новогодний дедлайн не давал развернуться. [Приходите, участвуйте, в выигрыше будут всё.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/924210/28748)

Comment: Ура-ура! Всех с праздником!

Comment: Равным образом! :) (с)

Comment: А что значит 7E3? Это 7527 лето от С.М.З.Х. или как?

Comment: @Bharata Это шестнадцатеричная шутка.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, как же это я не догадался! :-( Хороших вам праздников!

Comment: `"В уходящем году сообщество проделало невероятную работу, это видно по цифрам"` -- откровенно говоря, цифры как раз говорят о небольшом регрессе

Comment: @avp Все зависит о того, как на них смотреть. Например, если нормировать количество вопросов к новым участникам, то будет 1.5 к 2.2! =) Сообщество действительно растет и, что очень важно, в качественном плане. В этом году я ни раз столкнулся с тем, что на SOru ссылаются авторитетные люди при объяснении сложных задач (мол, посмотрите, как надо решать эту задачу); сообщество активно, например, динамично закрываются вопросы и еще более активно переоткрываются, если закрытие было спорным и тд. Мы активны, дружны, готовы помогать коллегам и это тоже рост.

Comment: Ну, смотреть-то можно по разному. А можно посмотреть, что новых участников стало меньше и ответов на один вопрос меньше и рост вопросов превышает рост ответов... / Но, в любом случае, с наступающим Новым Годом и пусть удача всегда будет с нами (а временные проблемы мы преодолеем)

Comment: @avp С наступающим! Обязательно преодолеем!

Answer (score 13):

> Знаете участника, который много помогал вам или другим и хотели бы его
>   поблагодарить за доброту и отзывчивость?

---

Хотелось бы и от своего имени поблагодарить всех модераторов сообщества, особенно [**Nicolas Chabanovsky**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/6/nicolas-chabanovsky) за решение "непростых" ситуаций в сообществе :), за запись интересных видеочатов и в целом за ruSo.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Нельзя не поблагодарить [**@Grundy**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/186999/grundy), который продолжает помогать мне в jQuery (он же жиКвери, он же жуйКвери ...) и JS, а так же в других вопросах связанных с front-end.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

А еще хотелось бы поблагодарить [**@Alexandr_TT**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/28748/alexandr-tt), который за прошедший год значительно пополнил (и продолжает пополнять :) ) базу знаний по `svg` на ruSO. Его ответы читаешь как стать из блога и много чего нового узнаешь для себя.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Спасибо всем участникам и **С НОВЫМ ГОДОМ!**

**Успехов, мира и любви всем в новом году!**

Comment: Большое спасибо! =) Присоединяюсь к благодарности [@ Alexandr_TT](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/28748/alexandr-tt). Вы создали одно из лучших сообществ в сообществе: отличный SVG–чат, замечательное описание метки, постоянно пополняет ассоциации и тд. Большое вам спасибо!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky А ничего бы не получилось, если бы у нас на RUso, не было таких , профессиональных специалистов и просто замечательных людей, которые участвовали в этом. Не получилось бы без мощной и эффективной работы всего модераторского состава. Очень хочется в первую очередь и про каждого участника написать искренние добрые слова. Но увы, Новогодний дедлайн перешел в штормовую фазу :)))

Comment: Огромное спасибо user:213987 `@A K` Это его была идея и самое активное участие в пересозднии метки SVG. Долго мучились над описанием метки  всем составом сообщества, спорили до хрипоты, чуть не переругались :)  SVG чат создал user:211549 `@Air` потом уже присоединился и творчески работал по поддержке user:280567 `@Arthur` Мы все овнеры этого чата и продолжаем друг друга подстраховывать во время отсутствия кого-либо.  Огромное спасибо всем, с кем познакомился очно или заочно и работал на этом форуме. **С наступающим Новым Годом дорогие одноклубники!.**

Comment: @Alexandr_TT Пожалуйста, напишите ваши пожелания отдельным ответом! Мне кажется, ребятам будет приятно =)

Answer (score 10):

> Знаете участника, который много помогал вам или другим и хотели бы его поблагодарить за доброту и отзывчивость?

В уходящем году я занимался математикой, в частности статистикой. Для вычислений использовал Python. Львиную долу того, что я искал, было отвечено [@MaxU](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/211923/maxu?tab=profile) на разных сайтах Stack Exchange. [@MaxU](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/211923/maxu?tab=profile) также очень много помогал мне (и не только мне!) ответами на Stack Overflow на русском.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Большое спасибо!**

Comment: И это здорово! P.S. Картинка слишком маленькая, можно ее ещё покрупнее сделать плиз? *сарказм*